# Applescript to get a list of file's hashes in a folder

Tags: applescript

I'm working on a script that will grab all files in a folder and compute their hash, however I'm having trouble on what should be one of the most basic parts of the script - concatenating found files into a shell script that will find the hash. Specifically, my problem is with this line:

do shell script "/usr/bin/openssl sha1 " & quoted form of POSIX path of new_file

It's line 44 of the script as a whole, here: http://pastebin.com/fEuFg9xL

My error is "Can't make quoted form of POSIX path of item 1 of {the list of files} into type unicode text".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_file` is just a item of a list. You need it as text (like you already did couple of times in your code).

```
do shell script "openssl sha1 " & quoted form of POSIX path of (new_file as text)
```